# Left recursion detected in .jj file

Tags: java, recursion, compilation, javacc, left-recursion

Not sure what is causing this really. When I try to compile the file I get an error saying "Left recursion detected expression... -> fragment ... -> expression.

The area of code that has this is this section

```
void statement() : {}

{
    identifier() <ASSIGN> expression()
    | identifier() <ASSIGN> <STRING>
    | <EMARK> expression()
    | <QMARK> identifier()
    | identifier(arg_list())
    | <BEGIN>(statement() <SEMIC>)+ <END>
    | <IF> condition() <THEN> statement()
    | <IF> condition() <THEN> statement() <ELSE> statement()
    | <WHILE> (condition()) <DO> statement()
    | {}
}

void expression () : {}
{
    fragment()((<PLUS_SIGN> | <MINUS_SIGN> | <MULT_SIGN> | <DIV_SIGN>) fragment())*
}

void fragment () : {}
{
    identifier() | <NUM> | (<PLUS_SIGN> | <MINUS_SIGN>)fragment() | expression()
}
```

I'm not really sure how to go about fixing this problem and would appreciate any help with it!
Thanks!

Comment: FYI: +++++----+++6 would be a valid fragment

Comment: This assignment has been discussed in several recent stack overflow questions.  Check out questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287086/left-factoring-removing-left-recursion-javacc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364288/left-recursion-elimination-in-an-ll1-grammar .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void fragment() #void : {}
|<LBR> expression() <RBR>
```

Change the fragment production rule, where it has expression to include brackets on either side. This should solve your recursion problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your abstraction is just a little off.

```
(<PLUS_SIGN> | <MINUS_SIGN>)fragment()
```

is more of an expression which can negate a fragment

I would consider

```
void expression () : {}
{
    fragment()((<PLUS_SIGN> | <MINUS_SIGN> | <MULT_SIGN> | <DIV_SIGN>) fragment())*
    | <MINUS_SIGN> fragment()
    | <PLUS_SIGN> fragment()
}
```

I also belive that fragment does not need to be an `expression()` either the recursion is already encapsulated by `((<PLUS_SIGN> | <MINUS_SIGN> | <MULT_SIGN> | <DIV_SIGN>) fragment())*` being able to repeat

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried what you said and the error disapered, however I get 4 warnings now as follows:

Warning: Choice conflict involving two expansions at
         line 243, column 11 and line 244, column 11 respectively.
         A common prefix is: <ID>
         Consider using a lookahead of 2 for earlier expansion.

They are all similar to this, another one mentions a common prefix being if and not. Any ideas what this is telling me?

Comment: No sorry not able to help you there i'm not familiar with .jj i was only able to help your recursion problem because i have a little experience with haskell. Goodluck